# Limit access to GeoServer to localhost

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

In order to secure my datastores, I checked GeoServer authentication filters but I can't use it because I can't expose passwords or usernames in my js files. So decided to limit access to GeoServer to my web application (on the same server). 
I added a remote adress filter to my web.xml file and restarted GeoServer but I get 503 error 
here is the added filter :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And some details from log :

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Class loading error for holder Remote Address Filter@4dea763c==org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter,inst=false,async=false
```

I'm using GeoServer 2.16.2 platform-independent binary version.

Comment: Not sure about your setup, but tag indicates Tomcat. In that case you should start by binding tomcat to localhost. If you are running jetty behind tomcat you should also bind jetty to localhost to avoid malicious users go to the jetty port directly.

Comment: Yes I'm using jetty behind tomcat but I didn't understand your idea

Answer (score 0):

Jetty will actually host GeoServer and you use Tomcat as a reverse proxy in front of it. Right?

In that case you must first ensure that Jetty only listens to localhost, otherwise a user can circumvent the reverse proxy (Tomcat) and go straight to the port where Jetty hosts GeoServer. This can be done in start.ini by uncomment as described and change to localhost:

```
# What host to listen on (leave commented to listen on all interfaces)
# jetty.host=myhost.com
```

Actually jetty.host is deprecated and you should use jetty.http.host. It is also possible to add this argument as a commandline argument from where jetty is started

```
java -jar start.jar jetty.http.host=localhost
```

Additionaly, you do not open the firewall for the jetty port.

Once Jetty is secured you must also make sure the reverse proxy also only responds to requests from localhost. I have never used Tomcat but probably something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617/how-do-you-configure-tomcat-to-bind-to-a-single-ip-address-localhost-instead-o

Then again, do not open the firewall.